# Bootstrap Parallax Speed

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, css

Is there a way to change the speed of the parallax effect? As of right now, the way I have it set up is, the bottom of the image shows and as you scroll the image scrolls up as well. However if I want it, so on initial load, the image loads in the center and as you scroll up and down the page then the parallax image only moves up and down about 50px. So in the example I created below I would like the family's face to be in the center on load and as I scroll up and down only show maybe 50px about the heads and 50px below what is showing on initial load.

Here is what I have

```
#wrapper3 {
    background-image: url('http://www.geneva.edu/blog/_assets/shutterstock_261648890%20-%20Child%20and%20Family%20Services.jpg');
    background-attachment: fixed;
    min-height: 350px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: 50% 0;
    background-size: cover;
    display: block;

}
```

Here is my [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/25874/)

Comment: I don't see any parallax effect at all in the demo

Comment: @j08691 should be the third wrapper on the demo. with the picture of the family.

Comment: I see the image but it doesn't move. Don't you usually need some JavaScript for a parallax effect?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you trying to move the background image slightly slower than the scrollbar moves the window for a smoother effect?

```js
$(function(){
    var $el = $('#wrapper3');     
    $(window).scroll(function () {
        para($el);
    });
    para($el);
});
var speed = 0.2;
function para($el) {
    var diff = $(window).scrollTop() - $el.offset().top;
    var yPos = -(diff * speed);
    var coords = '50% ' + yPos + 'px';
    $el.css({
        backgroundPosition: coords
    });
}
```

```css
/* Latest compiled and minified CSS included as External Resource*/

/* Optional theme */
@import url('//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css');

body {
    margin: 10px;
    color: #fff;
}
h1 {
  margin-top: 0px;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
}

.wrap {
  height: 350px;
}

#wrapper1 {
  background-color: red;  
}

#wrapper2 {
  background-color: blue;  
}

#wrapper3 {
    background-image: url('http://www.geneva.edu/blog/_assets/shutterstock_261648890%20-%20Child%20and%20Family%20Services.jpg');
    background-attachment: fixed;
    min-height: 350px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: 50% 0;
    background-size: cover;
    display: block;

}

#wrapper4 {
  background-color: yellow;  
}
#wrapper5 {
  background-color: red;  
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrap" id="wrapper1">
<h1>
content here
</h1>
</div>
<div class="wrap" id="wrapper2">
<h1>
content here
</h1>
</div>
<div class="wrap" id="wrapper3">
<h1>
content here
</h1>
</div>
<div class="wrap" id="wrapper4">
<h1>
content here
</h1>
</div>
<div class="wrap" id="wrapper5">
<h1>
content here
</h1>
</div>
```

Comment: this definitely helps! Lets say I want to make the scroll of the image even slower would i just bring var speed = .1?

Comment: Yeah, you can even go lower by changing speed to 0.9 - Don't go too low or it won't look smooth anymore.